# Inputting three integers x,y, and z to see if any operation can be made on x and y to get z as a result

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactive-programming

Is there a function python that performs all types of math functions on two variables?

Comment: A single function, **no**. Especially since *all types of math functions* is quite broad…

Comment: I think `z * abs(x+y+0.5)^0 === z` for all integer values of x, y, and z

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that handles addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponents and modulo:

```
def all_operations(x, y, z):
    if x + y == z: 
        return True
    if x - y == z: 
        return True
    if x * y == z:
        return True
    if x / y == z:
        return True
    if x % y == z:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
x, y, z = 6, 7, 42

for f in dir(x):
    try:
        if getattr(x, f)(y) == z:
            print(f)
    except:
        pass
```

That example finds two operations:

```
__mul__
__rmul__
```